# Unable to upgrade Android studio in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently using android studio 2.0 but  wanted to update it to 2.1 as its  been released on the stable channel. Now when I press on "Update & Restart" button ,it downloads the patch and then will exit but wont restart by its own.So I am starting it manually to check if update was successful but it still shows android studio 2.0 and same dialogue "Android studio is ready to update". I did it many times but no success. I am using Linux  Ubuntu System 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Check, its 64 bit system

Comment: I'm having the same problem for updating from 2.1 to 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit

Comment: same here but the os is windows any body got solution.

Answer (score 12):

Try the following:

1. After the patch was downloaded and Android Studio closed, open the terminal
2. Go to your android studio folder, e.g.
   `cd ~/android-studio`
3. Go to `bin` subfolder: 
   `cd bin`
4. Make sure your `studio.sh` file has run permissions: 
   `chmod +x studio.sh`
5. Run Android Studio from here: `./studio.sh`

After that Android Studio will find the patch and install it. Then you may close Android Studio and run it the regular way (whatever way you prefer, I run it from Launcher pad).

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem. i logged as root user then updated the android 2.0 to 2.1  it worked fine and  got updated

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem.

In 64 bit machine android studio installed in 2 different version 32bit and    64bit. At the time of update and restart 32bit android studio selected by default.
and when it load 64bit android studio.

To solve this problem please select 64 bit at the time of update and restart.

hope it will work.

Comment: how to select 64 bit  it doesnot  show any option show  thr.

Comment: It give list of option at the time of update and restart.. choose 2nd option.

Comment: it only shows :1update&restart  2 release notes 3 ignoure this update 4 remind  me later

Comment: @KamalJha No, it didn't. Just download and close AS, and that is all.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution, you can download the Android Studio version that you want to upgrade to directly.  For instance, 2.1 is located here:

[2.1 @ Android Tools](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-1)

Make sure that you import your old settings.  Also, pull your SDK out of the old install folder and point the new installation at it, if necessary.  This will ensure consistency across installs.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is simple:

1. Make sure you can run android studio from command line using `studio.sh`
2. If you have an open project in android studio go in "File > Close project" and close it
3. A small window opens up, wait for the notification for the update to appear and click on it
4. If 3 doesn't work, close android studio, repeat number 1 and 3

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Start Android studio from /android-studio/bin/studio.sh, and then restart update process