# Updating android studio 2.0 to 2.1.1 over stable channel

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to update Android Studio 2.0 to 2.1.1 but the "Check for Updates" is showing downloading and AS is getting restarted, but it does not update the AS.
My current version details have been attached in the screen-[image]shot.

OS Details :
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

uname -a output :
Linux username 3.19.1 #2 SMP Thu Mar 12 13:50:18 IST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The AS is restarting and update is not applied. Let me know what am I doing wrong or its a bug within AS 2.0. I have went with the other available links related to the post but none helped to solve the issue.

Comment: can you tell, what you have tried ?

Comment: I tried with the update option provided. It just restart the AS. I don't see any error, nor it has problem with automatic restart. I start AS via terminal only as sudo user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to log in as a root user than try to update android studio to 2.1 through stable channel

else you can try out [these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131596/unable-to-update-android-studio-from-2-0-to-2-1),

Hope this helps.

Comment: It may be random and not a valid one, but I ignored the update and then deleted the ignored version from the update.xml config file. Then restarted the AS and clicked for update. It worked and updated the AS.