# Android studio can't be Updated , Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

i'm trying to Update My android studio for the latest version stable that recently released 2.2 Stable from my Current version 2.1.3 at Ubuntu this shows above android studio

[image: download from Android Studio]

after this finished it just close the android studio and when open it again no change it still version 2.1.3

it happen twice ?
how to solve this as this is the first time update from Ubuntu ?

Comment: what changes are you expecting ?

Comment: it is upgraded from 2.1.3 to 2.2

Comment: @MiDo: Go through this-->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131596/unable-to-update-android-studio-from-2-0-to-2-1/37322309#37322309
And follow "Orlangure" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with update my Android Studio.

Download archive from: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.0.12/android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip and unpack.

Delete the previous one and paste the new one. If you're have it on `opt` directory you would need to use `sudo` privileges to delete it.

Open Android Studio using `./bin/studio.sh`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem. I fixed it by granting write/read permissions from the android studio directory to my user, writing this on my terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/android-studio
```

After that I launched android studio from desktop entry (I don't think this really matters) and update worked fine.

Comment: This works as expected. I have a question though, does this set ownership literally to `$USER:$USER` so when directory ownership is checked it is evaluated at that moment to the current user? Or does it simply evaluate to the user who runs the `chown` command? Only asking because I believe the intention of using the `/opt` folder is to make android studio shared amongst machine users.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for participating  i found the answer in this link

[Unable to update Android studio from 2.0 to 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131596/unable-to-update-android-studio-from-2-0-to-2-1/37322309#37322309)

by give the android studio the permission to edit 
Thanks Ram

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out by changing the folder permission of

> /android-studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting Android studio using terminal use the following method

1. Open Android Studio and close all the opened projects
2. click on configure>create desktop entry
3. Now close the android studio
4. Now search for Android Studio and open the Android Studio from search option in the the desktop.
5. Now update the android studio using the normal flow.

:-) Try this, it will work