# Android studio update and restart doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, jetbrains-ide

In case of android studio or any other jetbrains ide update and restart doesn't work . When I got a notification a new update is available I click update and restart . Android studio download the update and restart but after restarting the version of android studio remains same . It happens also for other jetbrains ide . I have checked the following question but didn't came to any help

[Android Studio: “Update & Restart” doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379665/android-studio-update-restart-doesnt-work)

[Can't update Android Studio - no “Update and Restart” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906325/cant-update-android-studio-no-update-and-restart-button)

My OS is `ubuntu 16.04 64` bit

Comment: See this thread https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224919. Faced the same issue and i downloaded the new version separately and used.:(

Comment: You need to run the IDE through terminal

Comment: I always run it from terminal . sudo ./android-studio/bin/studio.sh

Comment: yup this doesn't work. As a work around, I simply download the latest stable zip from here[http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable] and replace the old android studio folder with the new one, all the settings remain the same.

Comment: just type `android-studio/bin/studio.sh` without any `./` or `sudo`

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42089627/4279735)

Comment: Please check the solution here
[Update Android Studio in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45769129/7444617)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure about the reason, but somehow when we start the IDE through desktop shortcut or launcher (in UBUNTU) the IDE's updater couldn't access the updater.
So to overcome this problem, I always start Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEs via **Terminal** this somehow solves my problem.

**please do not start the IDE by using `./studio.sh`, instead use `studio.sh` directly, obviously by specifying the whole path**

> P.S. I couldn't do much research on this weird behavior so can not say the reason why it happens this way. If anyone knows the reason please add the comment or edit this answer.

Comment: What do you mean using 'studio.sh' directly?

Comment: if you are newbie to linux, then open terminal in a folder where you have studio.sh file and just run the command `studio.sh` without any prefix or postfix

Comment: @getsadzeg , then please add the path to studio.sh to your profile. or read my previous comment again

Comment: No I think I don't understand. I enter specified directory, the path, and then run 'studio.sh', but it seems there is no command like that, only './studio.sh'

Comment: then you must probably search for "how to add command path to profile". i dont want to go off topic by answering another answer for different question. @getsadzeg